# Is there a way to filter a folder by dates Blue Prism

Tags: filter, collections, filtering, blueprism

I am having issues around [Utility - Collection Manipulation - Filter Collection]
I have a Get Files action which gets all the files from a particular folder and outputs them into a collection in Blue Prism (there are 14 .txt files)
I then use the Filter Collection Object to filter this folder "Files"
I am trying to only bring back results in the collection for where the "Created" (DateTime) = today or yesterdays date.

Date1( DateTime) FormatDateTime(Today()&" "&LocalTime(),"dd/MM/yyyy")
Date2(DateTime) FormatDateTime(DateAdd("9", "-2", Today())&" "&LocalTime(),"dd/MM/yyyy")

Filter Expression : "[Created] <= "&"'" &[Date1]&"' and [Created] >= "&"'" &[Date2]&"'"

There is no Error message and it doesn't output any results.
I am thinking that maybe Date1 and Date2 aren't being read as dates perhaps?

Any help on this matter would be greatly appreciated.

Regards,

Gary

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Part of the problem may be:
This: FormatDateTime(Today()&" "&LocalTime(),"dd/MM/yyyy")
Delivers this: 30/11/2020 ==> Note there's no time!

This: FormatDateTime(Today(),"dd/MM/yyyy") &" "&LocalTime()
Delivers this: 30/11/2020 11:45 ==> Time included!
Which might be what you're looking for.
This: FormatDateTime(Today()&" "&LocalTime(),"dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm") does the same.

Comment: Hi, That worked. My problem was as you said - it was only bringing back the date and 00:00:00 - It needed the current time also. Much appreciated